# Cardinality of sets and strings -> confused

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I have a question regarding the cardinality of sets and strings.

If $ \Sigma^* $ is empty, the cardinality is 1, because the empty word $ \varepsilon $ is counted.

If $ \Sigma^+ $ is empty, the cardinality is 0, because the empty word is excluded from the set.

If $ \Sigma $ includes at least one symbol, the cardinality of $ \Sigma^* $ is inifite.

If I use a string without the definition of $ \Sigma $, for example to define a variable, then I have problems to understand the cardinality. So if I set a variable to a string: $ a = "a" $, the cardinality of the string is 1. But if I set a variable to an empty string: $ a = "" $, the cardinality is also 1, because "" is the same as the empty word $ \varepsilon $.

The first time I noticed this was in a book whereas the definition of Pumping Lemma allows $ i=0 $ for the pumped word-part $ y $. Which means for me that $ y^0 = \varepsilon $ is allowed, because $ \varepsilon $ counts with 1. At the same time, others sources mention that it's not allowed to define $ y = \varepsilon $ for the Pumping Lemma.

Is the book wrong with allowing $ i = 0 $, or are the other sources wrong by disallowing $ y = \varepsilon $? Or do I completely misunderstand this?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the [definition of the Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Definition_and_notation). It is the union of the sets $\Sigma^0,\Sigma^1,...$. Regardless of $\Sigma$ it is always defined that $\Sigma^0=\{\epsilon\}$. So, always $\epsilon\in\Sigma^*$.

Comment: Now, for the [plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star#Kleene_plus) it is the same definition, but only the union of $\Sigma^1,\Sigma^2,...$ is taken. When $\Sigma$ is empty, you have that all $\Sigma^k$, for $k>0$, are empty. So, the union of all of them is still empty.

Comment: Thank you! For $ \Sigma^* $ I understand it. But what about the part-string in Pumping Lemma, is it wrong to allow $ y^0 $?

Comment: When in doubt of a hypothesis of a theorem, consult [its proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Proof_of_the_pumping_lemma). The $y$ in the pumping lemma corresponds to a substring that traverses a cycle of states in the FSA that accepts the language. You can put $y^0$, which corresponds to not entering that cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Pumping Lemma (for regular languages) we consider a division $w = xyz$ for a long enough world $w$.

In the Lemma it is required that $y\neq \varepsilon$ (or equivalently $|y|> 0$). The reason is very practical. When $y=\varepsilon$ no letters are pumped, and $y^i = \varepsilon$ for all $i$, and then in fact $xy^iz = w$ belongs to $L$ for all $i$. That makes the statement of the Lemma of no value: it is always true.

In the iteration $y^i$ we may take $i=0$. Practically that means that a piece of the string is deleted, rather than iterated. The proof of the Lemma holds in that case (repeating a loop in the automaton $i$ times), and moreover there are situations where taking $i=0$ in when applying the Lemma to non-regular languages leads to an easy contradiction.

As for one of your other observations, please note the difference between cardinality and length. A string has a length (the number of its letters) and a set of strings has a cardinality (the number of its elements). It is confusing to talk about the cardinality of a single string, in my opinion.

Comment: I was confused that a set with $ \varepsilon $ has the cardinality 1. The mistake in my thoughts was, that I counted $ \varepsilon $ itself for the cardinality. But it's not $ \varepsilon $ itself, it's because adding $ \varepsilon $ to a set, is just a new element in the set. $ \varepsilon $ will then have a cardinality of 0 outside of a set in a variable declaration. This makes totally sense to me now. :) So a string is not a set. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @user14116251 Just to reinforce what Hendrik Jan says, you shouldn't talk about the "cardinality" of a string, as it makes things confusing.  A string has a length, a set has cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the size of a set of things and the size of the things the set contains.

The empty set contains nothing. Its size (or cardinality of you want to be sesquipedalian) is 0.

A set of containing one thing has size 1. It doesn't matter whether the one thing is an elephant, a flea, or a string. If there is one thing, the cardinality is 1. That thing could even be a set, even the empty set. The empty set is a thing which contains nothing but it is not nothing. It is a thing, so it can be the element of another set.

A string is not a set, even though it consists of elements of a set of letters. It differs from a set in that its elements are ordered, and therefore might repeat. When we count the size, we count each repeated element too. But both a string and a set can be empty. The empty set has size 0 but it's also one thing. The empty string has size 0, and it is also a thing. (A different thing).

So,
$$\begin{align}\mid\{\}\mid&=0\\
\mid\{\{\}\}\mid&=1\\
\mid\{“”\}\mid&=1\\
\mid\{“”, \{\}\}\mid&=2\\
\end{align}$$

We usually talk about the *length* of a string (or other sequence) rather than its *cardinality*, but the two concepts are shown with the same operator (the pair of vertical bars above, also used for "absolute value"), because they are easily related. In fact, we can think of a string (or sequence) as a set of *mappings*, each integer in a contiguous finite range is mapped to a single character (or element of the sequence). Even though the two characters are the same, the mappings in $\{<1\to a>, <2\to a>\}$ differ (because the integers differ), and the two mappings clearly denote the string $aa$. The cardinality of the set of mappings is 2, just as is the length of the string.

The empty string corresponds to an empty set of mappings (as one might expect), so its cardinality is 0. (As we saw above, this is different from the cardinality of a *set* containing the empty string.)

---

Finally, your question about the pumping lemma is a different confusion, but still a confusion having to do with emptiness.

The pumping lemma states that $|y|>0$, so it is clear that $y$ cannot be  $\epsilon$. But it allows you to pump $y^i$ for any non-negative $i$. There is no contradiction here. $y^0 = \epsilon$ for any $y$, by definition. So the pumping lemma lets you produce a string where $y$ has been replaced with $\epsilon$ (in other words, deleted). That has nothing to do with the fact that the $y$ being eliminated actually existed in the original string. (Or perhaps it does, since eliminating nothing is a no-op.)

Comment: Thank you a lot too. I would give to green checkmarks, because both answers helped me a lot. Anyway, it's only possible to give one. I'm sorry for this. But I want to point out that both answers are very helpful, if someone else sees this too.